# Before/after 15th day of the month

Tags: sql-server, days

I wanted to set the @startdate and @enddate automatically, depending on whether the query is run before or after the 15th day of the month.

```
select case @startdate when DAY(getdate())>15 -- etc.
```

but it doesn't like the syntax of >15 or =15.  I know DAY() returns an integer (today's result is 25), so I don't know why that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CASE` structure has two forms. Either you have

```
CASE expression
     WHEN value THEN result
     WHEN value THEN result
     ...
     ELSE
END
```

Or else you have

```
CASE
     WHEN boolean-expression THEN result
     WHEN boolean-expression THEN result
     ELSE
END
```

In your problem, you want the second form. Here is what you want:

```
SELECT @startdate = CASE WHEN DAY(getdate())>15 THEN ... ELSE ... END
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a total noob! I thought Day() was the problem and couldn't find any helpful info on that. Should've checked my CASE syntax...